# Installing GNU Prolog on Mac OS X (getting a Bus Error)

Tags: macos, compile, gnu, prolog

Just installed [gnu prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/) on Mac OS X 10.4 but it is not working.  When I go:

```
% ./gprolog 
Bus error
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How did you install it?  Maybe you should try a packaged version such as [Fink's](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gprolog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [bus error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) is similar to a segmentation fault.  This probably indicates a bug in gprolog, one of its libraries, or your compiler.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too.  Any fixes?

Comment: @sixty, no, but I would try the [Fink version](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gprolog).