# Prolog for the Mac

Tags: macos, installation, compile, prolog

For one of my classes I need to write several prolog programs.  Can someone suggest a mac friendly prolog compiler?  I tried gnu prolog but when it [doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/146973/installing-gnu-prolog-on-mac-os-x-getting-a-bus-error) for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said there, I would try packaged versions.  Fink has [gprolog](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gprolog) and [swi-prolog](http://www.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/swi-prolog).

Comment: Hey, I just tried that.  But not having any luck.  Created a new post: http://superuser.com/questions/146988/mac-os-x-trying-to-install-prolog-using-fink