# Mac OS X: Trying to install prolog using fink

Tags: macos, installation, compile, fink, prolog

I am trying to install prolog on Mac OS X 10.4.11.

I just downloaded fink because I think that that should help me and I am trying to get either:

[Package swi-prolog-5.8.1-2](http://www.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/swi-prolog)

or

[Package gprolog-1.3.1-1](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gprolog?rel_id=10.4-i386-current-unstable)

But I am not having any luck.

Here is what I was doing:

```
% fink install swi-prolog-5.8.1-2
Information about 1723 packages read in 0 seconds.
Failed: no package found for specification 'swi-prolog-5.8.1-2'!
%
```

**Question 1**: Are these what I want to download?

**Question 2**: Why isn't fink working?

---

**Update**

```
% apt-cache search prolog --full
Package: yap
Source: yap
Version: 4.4.4-1002
Priority: optional
Section: languages
Maintainer: Matthias Neeracher <neeracher@mac.com>
Depends: readline-shlibs (>= 4.3-1028), gmp-shlibs (>= 4.1.4-1), libmpfr1-shlibs, darwin (>= 8-1)
Architecture: darwin-i386
Filename: dists/fink-0.8.1/main/binary-darwin-i386//languages/yap_4.4.4-1002_darwin-i386.deb
Size: 2112546
Installed-Size: 6400
MD5sum: f78c8cd4534426ac799dae84ff3fea14
Description: Yet another prolog
 A high speed implementation of the Prolog programming language.
 .
 Web site: http://yap.sourceforge.net
 .
 Maintainer: Matthias Neeracher <neeracher@mac.com>
builddependsonly: Undefined
```

**Question:** Does this mean that Prolog is installed?  How do I find out where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```
fink install swi-prolog
```

The package name is swi-prolog.  Fink will take care of getting the right version.  You may also find apt-cache helpful:

```
apt-cache search prolog
```

EDIT: I think the issue is that swi-prolog and gprolog are in the unstable section.  The [Fink FAQ](http://www.finkproject.org/faq/usage-fink.php?phpLang=en#unstable) explains how to turn unstable on.  After following those instructions, you should be able to install them.

[yap](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/yap) comes up in apt-cache because it is in the stable section.  However, it's not installed.  If you choose to use that, you still have to do:

```
fink install yap
```

Comment: `fink install swi-prolog`: gives the exact same output

Comment: `% apt-cache search prolog` Produces: 
`yap - Yet another prolog`